# Failed to upload file to server using Python Requests

Tags: python, forms, python-requests, multipartform-data

I use Requests and python2.7 in order to fill some values in a form and upload (submit) an image to the server.

I actually execute the script from the server pointing to the file I need to upload. The file is located in the /home directory and I have made sure it has full permissions.

Although I get a 200 Response, nothing is uploaded. This is part of my code:

```
import requests
try:
    headers = {
        "Referer": 'url_for_upload_form',
        "sessionid": sessionid # retrieved earlier
    }
    files = {'file': ('doc_file', open('/home/test.png', 'rb'))}
    payload = {
        'title': 'test',
        'source': 'source',
        'date': '2016-10-26 02:13',
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken # retrieved earlier - 
     }
    r = c.post(upload_url, files=files, data=payload, headers=headers)
    print r.headers
    print r.status_code
except:
    print "Error uploading file"
```

As I said I get a 200 Response and the headers returned are:

```
{'Content-Language': 'en', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Set-Cookie': 'csrftoken=fNfJU8vrvOLAnJ5h7QriPIQ7RkI755VQ; expires=Tue, 17-Oct-2017 08:04:58 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/', 'Vary': 'Accept-Language, Cookie', 'Server': 'nginx/1.6.0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Date': 'Tue, 18 Oct 2016 08:04:58 GMT', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Am I missing something basic here?

Comment: Are you sure , the server takes a **POST** request ? Check network elements carefully , there may be **.PUT()** before POST : **requests.put(url, data=None, **kwargs)**

Comment: Thanks. The server must takes POST request cause in the previous step (which I don't show here) I make a POST request to login to the page.

Comment: It is difficult to understand & interpret without looking at the page elements , Also is c = requests.Session() ?

Comment: Try to send request without `headers`. Also clarify what is `c`?